# Australian PR points process with different fields work experience

Tags: immigration, australia, australian-citizens

I completed my Bachelors in Chemistry in 2006 and later started working for a social organization as a social worker till 2010 June. Then I moved to USA and completed my MBA in finance. Later, I started working as Programmer in USA since 2016.

Now my question is since both field social worker as well as Programmer as in the list of Skills for 189 category, can I add the work experience (3.5 years as a social worker and 2 years as a programmer) to gain points for the Australian PR processing?

Thank you,
Shankar

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't add the experience together for 2 unrelated professions. You need to apply for the 189 visa as a named profession and the experience needs to relate to that profession - so in my case I applied as a Analyst Programmer and all experience was measured against that criteria.

So pick the profession which will earn you the most points. Don't worry if you won't actually be working in that profession. Once you land in Australia with a shiny new 189 visa you are free to work in any job you choose.

Good luck with your application